# How can I setup simple-scan on my nixos host for an HP OfficeJet Pro

Tags: scanning, nix, nixos, sane

I have an HP OfficeJet Pro 8610, and a nixos host.
I can easily set up the printer in cups, using `hplip` and a `hp:/net/...` address.

But how can I set up scanning with simple-scan?  It doesn't recognize the existence of the printer, neither does `sane-find-scanner` or `scanimage -L`.
I have tried running `hp-setup`, but that fails complaining of `error: No module named enum`.  I have tried installing `python27Packages.enum` in my user environment and also in the system environment, but no dice.

Thanks,

Comment: You'll want to override the derivation `hp-setup` comes from to add `enum` to *its* dependency list. Sorry, can't really give more detailed advice without building/testing a fix for the bug (which, if not in a hurry, you could report to nixpkgs) myself.

Comment: Not to worry @CharlesDuffy - all help is welcome, thank you for the pointer, it was enough to prompt me to find an existing bug (which has already been fixed!) [here](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/58515).  That isn't all there is to it, unfortunately, but I now have scanning working and will update the question with how, for the benefit of fellow travellers, later today or tomorrow.

Comment: BTW, it's generally acceptable and welcome to add your own answer, rather than editing an answer into a question. (That way the answer can be marked accepted -- albeit after a timeout -- so your question doesn't show up as unsolved).

Comment: (As another aside -- it'll help keep the question open here on SO if you keep the answer narrowly focused on "this is how one can write code to modify a Nix derivation to do fix a Python dependency error", vs "this is how one can make a HP printer work with simple-scan on NixOS"; questions about OS configuration as such generally belong on [unix.se] instead, but Nix being a programming language in its own right makes it the distinction more malleable and thus provides a window to argue that either site could be appropriate).

Comment: Ah now, I hadn't realized that I was in the wrong place - thanks!  I've posted an answered question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/518687/how-do-i-set-up-scanning-from-an-hp-officejet-pro-on-nixos/518688#518688)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the nix derivation was missing a dependency; specifically on the `enum` package in python.  Luckily, somebody else already spotted and fixed this [here](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/58515); one just needs to update one's nix channel to pick it up.

To use scanning in general in NixOS with an OfficeJet Pro 8610, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/518687/how-do-i-set-up-scanning-from-an-hp-officejet-pro-on-nixos/518688#518688).